# apache error log AH00135: Invalid method in request "GET /cgi-bin/php HTTP/1.0

Tags: logging, apache-2.4

Today I have noticed a lonely error (for the last week) inside of my error log file:

```
[datetime] [core:error] [pid 11220] [client 187.33.2.88:34964] AH00135: Invalid method in request "GET /cgi-bin/php HTTP/1.0
```

I am on apache 2.4.10 and php 5.5.17. Is there any reason to be worried about it? What might have caused it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's apache complaining about an invalid request method it received from the specified ip.
Looks like someone/something sent `"GET` instead of `GET`.

Might be a broken script, a proxy server or some guy doing the request using telnet.

Nothing to worry about.